# Oracle SQL to get min number from case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, function, case, min

I have this query below (in Oracle PL/SQL) which I am trying to pull a price, it seems to give me 3 records but I only want one.  I want to show the lowest rate if I run into this kind of scenario, can I possibly put a min function around the 'rate' field which is in the case statement below?

```
  select /*+ rule */ a.skucode as skucode,a.sizecode as 
        sizecode,b.colourdescription as colourdesc, a.season as season, 
        (case when sp.eventnbr in (select eventnbr from event where sysdate       
        between eventbegints 
        and eventendts) then rate else sellprice end) as listprice 
                  from sku a, colour b, skuprcevnt sp 
                  where a.skucode = '00000000051361264-04'
                 --" and a.storecode = '00000' " +
                  and a.storecode = '00000'
                  and a.colourcode = b.colourcode 
                  and a.skucode=sp.skucode(+) 
                  order by a.skucode, a.sizecode, b.colourdescription;
```

This gives the following result (but I want to see the price of 76.99 only):

```
SKUCODE             SIZECODE   COLOURDESC   SEASON  LISTPRICE
00000000051361264-04    XL     BLACK        FA-13       155
00000000051361264-04    XL     BLACK        FA-13       155
00000000051361264-04    XL     BLACK        FA-13       76.99
```

Comment: Yes you can put a min function around the case statement.  You will also need a group by to determine what to group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MIN in the column list if you group the query appropriately:

```
select a.skucode,
       a.sizecode,
       b.colourdescription as colourdesc,
       a.season, 
       MIN(case
             when sp.eventnbr in (select eventnbr
                                    from event
                                    where sysdate between eventbegints 
                                                      and eventendts)
               then rate
             else sellprice
           end) as listprice 
  from sku a
  INNER JOIN colour b
    ON b.colourcode = a.colourcode 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN skuprcevnt sp
    ON sp.skucode = a.skucode
  where a.skucode = '00000000051361264-04' and
        a.storecode = '00000'
  GROUP BY a.SKUCODE, a.SIZECODE, b.COLOURDESCRIPTION, a.SEASON
  order by a.skucode, a.sizecode, b.colourdescription, a.SEASON;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your select clause will never affect the number of rows returned by a query. You need a filter in the WHERE clause along the lines of WHERE rate = (select min(rate)  sku where skucode=a.skucode ).

Your example is more complicated so the actual filter would be bigger but that's just an idea of what it would look like.